# multiple notification intervals for different groups

Tags: nagios

Is it possible for me to setup notifications on a host for two different groups but have the interval for each group different?

Our network staff would only like one email when a site goes down and one when it comes back up.  But the helpdesk supervisor wants emails sent to the helpdesk every 30 minutes while a site is down.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at [Notification Escalations](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/escalations.html) within the Nagios documentation. You can set up your base notifications to your networking team to not recur, but have your helpdesk escalation re-notified every 30 minutes. Use `first_escalation = 1` and `last_escalation = 0` to ensure that the escalation triggers on the first notification and does not end until the host/service state returns to OK.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to do this via service escalations - i.e. for your network staff have the notification interval be 0 and then create a service escalation associated with the helpdesk supervisor with it set to 30.

Do you really want to do this on the host or the site (which would be a service check instead of a host check)

```
define hostescalation {
        host_name                 <host>
        contact_groups            helpdesk-supervisors
        notification_interval     30  
        first_notification        2
        last_notification         0
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response it looks like that will work.  Yes I mean host, when I said "site" I meant WAN site (i.e. remote router), not website.